# Недопустимый параметр C#

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы, bitmap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В результате работы следующего участка кода возникает исключение   `Application.Run(new Form1());`

```
 private void upload_image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name;
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog(); 
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            name = open.FileName;
            using (Bitmap pict = new Bitmap(name))
            {
                picture.Image = pict;
            }
        }
    }
```

Что в данном методе не так? В чём причина и как можно исправить?

Comment: Из Вашего сообщения лишь ясно, что Вы не можете сконструировать форму и совершенно не ясно, причем здесь код, висящий на событии

Comment: ошибка кстати правда вываливается именно там

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов без данного кода программа нормально работает, исключение лишь вылезает после вызова этого метода

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не знаю как объяснить, но делайте так, работает:

```
private void upload_image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        picture.Image = Image.FromFile(open.FileName);
    }
}
```

Очень подозреваю, что ошибка из-за отличающихся размеров изображений и `pictureBox` или преобразования из `Bitmap`

Comment: В первой версии Вашего ответа я подумал *что за магия?*, но потом уже дошло )))

Comment: А чтоб не было недоумения и ссылок на магию, нужно использовать try{...} catch(), там где нужно (в данном случае это try { picture.Image = Image.FromFile(open.FileName); } ).

Comment: Не поможет, пролетит мимо `catch`

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, мне до сих пор интересно, с чего Вы взяли, что это было консольное приложение? )

Comment: @Denis Bubnov, Вы меня с кем-то перепутали. Посмотрите мои комментарии к вопросу

Comment: @DenisBubnov да, тот ответ удалил автор)

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, простите, если обознался. Просто хотел узнать откуда было взято такое мнение.

Comment: @Denis Bubnov, очень плохо, что ответ был удален. Вам что-то показалось. Извините, но у меня нет времени на обсуждение чьих-то галлюцинаций. Есть вопросы о технике программирования?

Comment: @Denis Bubnov "...простите, если обознался..." - вопрос снят, я готов обсуждать тонкости программирования